# Ninject intercept all virtual methods by default

Tags: logging, ninject, aop

I'm trying to add logging in to application. Based on this blog post 
[Logging with Ninject](https://buildplease.com/pages/Ninject-Interception-Serilog-Part1-072020/)

It blog solves almost all my problems and even more. However there is one small issue that I cannot solve.

How to configure Ninject to always intercept virtual methods (with default interceptor) without configuring it on class or method level?

Comment: You should program to interfaces; not to base classes. This will solve your problems.

Comment: Hi @steven thanks for your answer I'm quite sure I don't understand what do you mean. Maybe I've not explained what I'd like to achieve. I want all virtual methods to always leave trace in logs "Method x run with params x' y'" but I don't want to do `Bind<IInterceptedTestClass>()
   .To<InterceptedTestClass>()
   .Intercept().With<LogInterceptor>();` nor add any atributes to calses or methods.